# Laravel - Discount by category and product - Trait or Model?

Tags: php, laravel

I am making an application for an e-commerce and I have the following scenario:

- I need to be able to apply discounts to products based on their Product ID or the category assigned to them. Example: A 50% discount to the product with the ID 3 and a 25% discount to the products that have the category "cars"
- Both options must be compatible, that is, a product can have a discount for its ID and also for the category assigned to it.

In the database I was thinking of creating two tables to solve this: the table "**product_discount**" (id_product, discount_percentage) and the table "**category_discount**" (id_category, discount_percentage).

Finally, my question comes at this point: when creating the models I had thought of doing the following:

- Create "**Discount**" **class** with the "discount_percentage" attribute
- Create "**CategoryDiscount**" **trait** with the "id_category" attribute
- Create "**ProductDiscount**" **trait** with the "id_product" attribute

In this way, you could unify the "discount_percentage" attribute in the "Discount" class, and when you want to retrieve the discounts of a product, you would only have to instantiate that class.

Another option would be to create "CategoryDiscount" and "ProductDiscount" as models and inherit both from the "Discount" class, but this would be a problem, since both classes could be instantiated and it is something I don't want, since I want to be able to retrieve all the discounts simply using the methods of the "Discount" class.

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Don't you have a `Product` and a `Category` model/table where the respective `discount_percentage` could go into?

Comment: Correct, I have the "Category" and "Product" models, but I had not considered the option to add the "discount_percentage" in these models. Wouldn't it be a better option to separate them into specific tables for discounts?

Comment: With Laravel you can have a single `discounts` table and use a [polymorphic one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations) relationship. In this case your "discountable" models would be either category or product and a single row in `discounts` will apply to either a category or product but not both

Comment: And in your `Product` model, you can implement the relations with `hasOne` (productDiscount) and `hasOneThrough()` (categoryDiscount) or `hasMany` (productDiscount) and `hasManyThrough()` (categoryDiscount) respectively and combined with an accessor.

Comment: @DonPepeYLosGlobos Well, normally I would agree if there were multiple discounts and additional information applied to them, but I didn't see that in your example. That's why I asked.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, guys, your opinion has been great! I hadn't thought about the polymorphic relationships option, but I think that's the approach I'm going to use. Thanks again!